# How to calculate the values of a version of a conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

So I am just learning about conditional expectation in the modern probability sense. I understand that it is a random variable.

What I am having a hard time understanding is how you calculate the outputs of the conditional expectation in specific examples.

For instance I'm reading through this example and the author doesn't explain how they get their values for the conditional expectation:

> Let $\Omega=\{a,b,c\}, \ \mathcal{F}_1=\sigma(\{a\}), \ \mathcal{F}_2=\sigma(\{c\}).$ Take $X(b)=1, \ X(a)=X(c)=0.$ In this case we have
>   $$
> E(X|\mathcal{F}_1)(a)=0, \ E(X|\mathcal{F}_1)(b)=\frac{1}{2}, \ E(X|\mathcal{F}_1)(c)=\frac{1}{2}.
> $$

Could somebody please explain how they arrived at these values?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have $\cal F_2$? The conditional expectation gives the 'best estimate' given the specified $\sigma$-field. Here ${\cal F_1} = \{ \emptyset, \{a\}, \{b,c\} , \Omega\}$, so $E[X | {\cal F_1}]$ will equal the corresponding averages.

Comment: Sorry, there is more to the example, they calculate $E(E(X|\mathcal{F}_1)|\mathcal{F}_2)$ as well. So for my question $\mathcal{F}_2$ is not needed.

Comment: Computing the conditional expectation is straightforward when the $\sigma$-field consists of 'atoms' like $\{a\}, \{b,c\}$ over which the averages are $0, {1 \over 2}$ respectively..

Comment: Saying that it is straight forward isn't helpful to me. I was hoping that somebody could go through how to calculate it in this instance since I don't understand how you do that.

Comment: They don't say anything about the underlying measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\sigma$-field ${\cal F_1}$ is given by $\{\{a\}, \{b,c\}, \emptyset , \Omega \}$. The definition is that a version of $E[X|{\cal F_1}]$ is a ${\cal F_1}$ measurable random variable $Y$ such that
$\int_A Y = \int_A X$ for any $A \in {\cal F_1}$.

$Y$ must be ${\cal F_1}$ measurable. In particular, this means it must take the same value at $b$ and $c$ (otherwise it would not be measurable). Hence
it has the form $Y = Y_1 1_{ \{a\} } + Y_2 1_{ \{b,c\} }$, and all we need
to do is to compute values for $Y_1,Y_2$ that satisfy the defining equation.

Choosing $A = \{a\}$  shows that $ \int_A Y= Y_1 p \{a\} = X(a) p \{a\}= 0$,
hence if $p\{a\} > 0$ we have $Y_1 = X(a)$ and if $p \{a\} = 0$, the value
doesn't matter (we only need the values to be defined ae.), so we can choose
$Y_1 = X(a)$.

Choosing $A= \{b,c\}$ gives $ \int_A Y= Y_2 p \{b,c\} = \int_A X = X(c) p \{c\} + X(b) p \{b\}$. As above, if $p\{b,c\} >0$ we have
$Y_2 = {X(c) p \{c\} + X(b) p \{b\} \over p \{b,c\} }$, and if $p\{b,c\} =0$,
we can pick any value.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. A lot of the sources I went through never bothered to actually work out an example like this, they just proved theorems.

Comment: I think you need to know $p \{b\}, p \{c\}$ to finish the computation. I think that your example assumes $p\{b\} = p \{c\}$.

Comment: I'm assuming that they are supposed to be $1/3$, although they didn't specify in the problem.

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as the value is the same for $b,c$, since it gets 'divided out'.

Comment: To illustrate, if $ p \{b\} = 0$, then we can take $E[X |{\cal F_1}] = 0$.